# Could not find SDK on kmm with AppCode

Tags: ios, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I am very new to kotlin multiplatform mobile and tryed to start with AppCode and the kmm plugin. Creating and running the project on Android worked fine, but when I want to build or run the App for iOS I get the following gradle error:

```sh
Execution failed for task ':iosApp:generateIosAppEditableXcodeproj'.

> Could not find SDK.

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

I develop on a MacBook Pro M1 with macOS 12.1 and xCode 13.2.1.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Possibly related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KMA-355
It seems like your Xcode does not have Command Line Tools installed. This can be changed by calling `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` or by installing them manually at the Xcode's `Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem.